# How can i have a cover background-image without any deformation?

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, background, background-image

(Sorry if my english isn't that good) I have a problem with my code, i'm trying to create a background-image fullsize screen but my image just distords itself in height or in lenght when it doesn't correspond to the size image. What I want to do is cropping it instead of deformint it... My code :

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid px-0">
    <main>
        <!-- Accueil -->
        <section>
            <div class="container justify-content-start">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="ressources/images/picto_appareil_photo.jpg" alt="" title="" width="200" height="200">
                <h2>Matheo TUMBARELLO</h2>
                <h1>Etudiant BUT informatique<br><br>Aspire à devenir développeur web & mobile fullstack</h1>
            </div>
        </section>
        
        <!-- Formations -->
        <section class=""> 

        </section>
        <div class="transition"></div>

        <!-- Compétences -->
        <section class=""> 

        </section>
        <div class="transition"></div>

        <!-- Portfolio -->
        <section class=""> 

        </section>
        <div class="transition"></div>

        <!-- Experiences -->
        <section class=""> 

        </section>
        <div class="transition"></div>

        <!-- Contact -->
        <section class=""> 
            <form>

            </form>
        </section>
    </main>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@keyframes zoomloop {
    0% {
      background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
    100% {
      background-size: 105% 105%;
    }
  }
section:first-child{
    height: 100vh;
    background: url("ressources/images/background_laptop.jpg") top right;
    background-position: cover;
    animation: zoomloop 5s infinite alternate;
}
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fu6Fp.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main error here is that `cover` is a value for `background-size` and not `background-position`

This should fix it:

```
background: url("ressources/images/background_laptop.jpg"); /*Remove initial top right instruction*/
background-size: cover;
background-position: 50% 50%;
```

If you want your image to keep ratio while making the zoom effect, you need the `auto` property. Depending on the image ratio, the zoom would apply either on the height, or width of your image

```
.image {
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
.image:hover {
    background-size: 105% auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you feedback, now it's quite working but when i resize the page in length, the height size of the image change and white spaces background appear on top and bottom of it. I think i didn't explain well, i would like to have a background like https://www.eness.fr/ has, when you resize the page, the height doesn't change but the image is cropped on size

Comment: That's just the first solution, aka `background-size: cover;`, however, the zoom can't apply with this setting because `cover` doesn't apply with a second value, you'd need a mask with your image and `transform: scale(1.1)` on that mask to have both `cover` and the zoom effect

Comment: Thank you ! it's working now :) i didn't even realised that i was using background size two times so that's why i couldn't fix anything... I just want to ask one more question : i created a parent to the div so i could do```overflow: hidden```, but all the text in the section with this background is concerned by the scale. I searched about the mask as you told me, but i don't really understand how can i use it, is this the only way to fix this problem ?

Comment: Scale will apply to all the children of the element, the mask is just a div with the window dimensions that goes underneath the content, and you apply that scale on that div only so it does the zoom effect without affecting its siblings